# Show that $\dfrac{d^{m-1}}{ds^{m-1}} \Big(\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} \Big) =- \sum_{|\gamma -t|<1} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)^m} + \mathcal{O} (\log t)$.

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-zeta, estimation

Eq. 2.1 in [Levinson's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69902273) states $$\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^m} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)^m} - \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)^m} = - \sum_{|\gamma -t|<1} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)^m} + \mathcal{O} (\log t).$$ And it is stated that this is derived by $N(T+1) - N(T) = \mathcal{O} (\log t)$, where $N(T)$ are the number of zeros of $\zeta(\sigma + it)$ for $0 < t \le T$.

My question is how to derive Eq. 2.1 *rigorously*? Roughly speaking $\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^m}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)^m}$ and $\sum_{|\gamma -t| \ge 1} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)^m}$ are $\mathcal{O} (1)$  (?) and thus are dominated by $\mathcal{O} (\log t)$. If so, then what is the use of $N(T+1) - N(T) = \mathcal{O} (\log t)$ (as the paper claims)?

Comment: the use is for $m=1$ essentially (though one can also use it to show that $\sum 1/|\rho|^m < \infty, m \ge 2$ which indeed makes all the terms except those with $|t-\gamma|<1$ to add to $O(1)$

Comment: @Conrad, for $m=1$, the first term $\frac{1}{(s-1)^m} = O(1) = O(\log t)$, but for the rest how do you conclude $- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)} - \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)} = - \sum_{|\gamma -t|<1} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)} + \mathcal{O} (\log t)$?

Comment: the above is not a correct formula for $m=1$ since the LHS is divergent - the correct formula for $m=1$ has more terms (you need to introduce convergence factors like $-1/2n, n \ge 1$ etc and Levinson refers to Titchmarsh for it; you can find a proof of the case $m=1$ in Titchmarsh chapter 9, page 217

Comment: @Conrad, I see; thanks! But it is valid for m=1 also, as Eq. 9.6.1 says (?)

Comment: again I think you are confusing two things - the approximation functional equation of $\zeta'/\zeta$ in terms of the non trivial zeroes - 9.6.1 in Titchmarsh is of course true; howver what is not true is that you can use $- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)} - \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)}$ to derive it or use that for anything for that matter since that is divergent; the correct expression to use is $- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( \dfrac{1}{(s+2n)}-1/(2n)) - \sum_{\rho} (\dfrac{1}{(s-\rho)}-1/\rho)$

Comment: I got it! Thank you :)